# How to allow insertion of only those students of age 18 and above?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that allows details of only students older than 18 to be inserted.

Table structure:

```
create table student(
uidno numeric(6) primary key,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(20),
dob date
);
```

And here is my PL/SQL trigger:

```
create or replace trigger checkAge
before insert
on student
for each row

declare

curr_year int;
dob_year int;

begin

select extract(year from current_date) into curr_year from dual;
select extract(year from dob) into dob_year from :new where uidno = :new.uidno;

if curr_year - dob_year < 18 then
    raise_application_error(-20098,'Not above 18 years of age');

end if;

end;

/
```

I keep getting the following errors:
9/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/55     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW'
9/60     PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: problem is in highlighted *new* in this sentence : select extract(year from dob) into dob_year from `:new` where uidno = :new.uidno

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yeah, I guess I've used the wrong syntax. I also tried using: 'select extract(year from :new.dob) into dob_year from :new'

Comment: to use "from :new" is wrong as a table name. Shouldn't it be "from student"?

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. How else could I extract the year from the new entry? Thanks.

Comment: this works : `dob_year := to_number(to_char(:new.dob,'rrrr'));`

Comment: Ah finally! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: by the way : `curr_year := extract(year from current_date);`

Comment: Why do you want to use a trigger for this? Are you learning about triggers and practice writing them? Otherwise the normal way to enforce such conditions is to add a constraint on the column, not a trigger. And if you need to check that TODAY (not sometime this year) a person is at least 18 years of age, you shouldn't use `extract(year from...)` but rather something like `sysdate >= add_months(:new.dob, 18*12)`

Comment: @mathguy Learning about them, part of my computer practicals.

Answer (score 0):

as Barbaros says, that is how to extract the year from a field type date.

```
dob_year := to_number(to_char(:new.dob,'rrrr'));
```

But if you want to calculate an age the correct way is:

```
age := floor (month_between (sysdate, :new.dob) / 12);
```